# Make a div stretch across the page overflowing its containing div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having difficulty making a div stretch across the page overflowing its containing div.

I am using WordPress child theme of twenty thirteen theme importing bootstrap CSS file only, no JavaScript files (yet anyway!).

I am using this div called section to add styling just to add a background image or colour like this websites orange section please see link below:

[Flat Web Design](http://www.triplagent.com/?utm_source=CMblog&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=FlatDesign)

I have tried

```
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
```

but position: absolute seems to play havoc with the grid.The section div appears in the correct place, however the following divs sit on top of the "section" div.

I am aware of HTML5 section tag. But as I understand it, it is not best practice to use section for styling only, but to use a div instead? However I have experimented with the section tag and I have the same problem.

I hope someone can advise how I can make a div stretch across the page overflowing its containing div? Can this be done without position absolute?

Thanks in advance

My MarkUp

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="container">
<div class="section">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php the_field('title'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php the_field('content'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php the_field('image-item'); ?>
                </div>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.entry-header,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary,
.entry-meta{
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1150px;
width: 95%;
```

}

```
.section{
background:#e8e5ce;  
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this kind of layout you can't use a single container, each section should have its own `.container` element, this way the section covers the width of the window but the content is centered:

**HTML**

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php the_field( 'title'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php the_field( 'content'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php the_field( 'image-item'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.section{
    background-color:#e8e5ce;  
}
```